# How could we solve the HTTP request error? Error 429, Too Many requests

Tags: audio, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-dl

I was a tool called youtube-dl which is command line tool for downloading youtube videos/audios.
When running the command below

`youtube-dl https://youtube.com/watch?v=$1 \
    --quiet --extract-audio --audio-format wav \
    --output "$outname.%(ext)s`

I'm encountering Error 429, Too Many requests. Any work around this.

I'm trying to download audios from audio-set dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You’re receiving the 429 Too Many Requests error message because the user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time (could be a plugin, a DDos, or something else). It’s a server telling you to please stop sending requests.

[click on it](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-wordpress-429-too-many-requests-error/)

Comment: I'm aware of that fact, is there any tool which can momentarily change IP address.